# how to down load Video and save it in ipad.?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

How do I download **video** in iPad. I have the URL of a video and I need to download it and save it in my iPad database and used it offline.  Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

I try this on code but it is not working to save the file. After this code I use Media Player to play it. But it is not downloaded so I can't play.

```
NSURL *url = // some-URL;
NSData *yourVedioFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURLURLWithString:url]];

//Store the Data locally as Video File

NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourVideoName.mov"];
[yourVedioFileData writeToFile:yourFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *imagelist = URL_NAME;

NSData *yourVideoFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagelist]];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *yourFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR_File_Name.mov"];

[yourVideoFileData writeToFile:yourFilePath atomically:YES];
```